# How can I configure and use a HUAWEI E173 HSDPA USB Modem?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, wireless

I've tried a lot with different ways but I need something real to configure it here in Mexico.

I can't work it on with no Ubuntu's OS (10.04 and 11.10).

Can you please help sort this out?

Comment: Can you edit your question and point us where are you stuck and what have you tried until now? (link guides and other pages if you like)

Answer (score 1):

step 1. log in to the computer.

step 2. plug in the dongle.

step 3. wait 20sec after you can see in your network option in the taskbar. Next click it enable the mobile broadband.

step 4. set apn.